# How to validate the kid of JWT Security token in c#?

Tags: c#, token, jwt, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization

Hi I am using "JwtSecurityTokenHandler"'s "ValidateToken" to validate the token with the certificate as follows :

```
private ClaimsPrincipal GetClaims(X509Certificate2 validatingCer, string token)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler JwtSecurityTokenHandler;
        X509SecurityKey securityKey = new X509SecurityKey(validatingCer);
        TokenValidationParameters validationParams= new TokenValidationParameters {
            // Validation states:
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            // Validation parameters:
            ValidIssuer = "Test",
            ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
        };
        SecurityToken validatedSecurityToken;
        ClaimsPrincipal claims = JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedSecurityToken);

        return claims;
    }
```

Here the "token" contains a different "kid" value and the "validatingCer" contains different "kid" but still the "ValidateToken" does not validate the same ?

Comment: You have to expose the public key which you can get by right clicking on the certificate and do Export (dont include the private key) on the MMC. Then whoever has to validate the token would do `var x509 = new X509Certiicate2(pathToExportedCert);` Or you can also use the byte array ctor and have the public key encoded in base64.

Comment: @Thennarasan the public key here is "securityKey" and the "token" is the JWT Security token and I am trying to validate this token with "security" (which is having a different KeyId than I have in "token" header).